# How to capture webpage to PDF using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, export

I am creating a web with some reporting in DataGrid and some display graphical using MSchart control in asp.nt 2.0.

Now I would like to export the displayed page to PDF, So customers can export the data/details in pdf for future use, I tried the ITextSharp but it giving exception in html parsing.

So please let me know how can I do that ?

Thanks,
Laxmilal

Answer (score 0):

ITextSharp will only support a limited number of html tags. Check the list of supported tags: Sorry, can't find the file! :-(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at WebToPDF.NET which is a .NET component written in C# that converts HTML to PDF. The converter supports HTML 4.01, XHTML 1.0, XHTML 1.1 and CSS 2.1 including page breaks, forms and links. It passes all W3C tests (except BIDI).